# Webpack Javascript Library - How to import Class directly?

Tags: javascript, webpack, import, output, webpack.config.js

I made new Javascript library with Webpack. I want to import class from this library directly. However, I need to put '.default' to run MyClass. I don't want to use '.default'. I just want to use MyClass directly. What should I do to solve it?

```
//index.js
export default class Myclass {
//...}
```

```
//webpack.config.js
output: {
   library: 'MyClass',
   libraryTarget: 'umd',
   libraryExport : "default",
   filename: 'index.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
},
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I want to share it.

First, you have to set webpack.config.js like this.

```
//webpack.config.js
output: {
   library: 'MyClass',
   libraryTarget: 'umd',
   libraryExport : "default",
   filename: 'index.js',
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
}
```

When you just import MyClass from other javascript projects, you could call MyClass without '.default'.

```
import MyClass from 'MyLibary';
const newInstance = new MyClass();
```

However when you import MyClass dynamically, you have to set 'default'.

```
const { default: MyClass } = await import('MyLibrary');
const newInstance = new MyClass();
```

It's done!